# Is this a piano?

Tags: sound-design, sound

do you know how can I recreate this? It seems a piano.

https://www.facebook.com/kygoofficial/videos/886958051367329/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a piano patch with some fast delay and reverb. I would keep the delay with a small amount of wet signal and you can either put a reverb after the chain to or as a send from the original piano sound. You can experiment with both but it is most likely a piano with those effects.